# Landscape RestAPI: How to tell GetComputers to return only those devices that have sent inventory in the past 90 days?

Tags: landscape, apic

The removal profiles methods have the days_without_exchange parameter; however, I do not see how I can use that parameter with other methods, so does anyone know how I can achieve my goal?